# Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('content'); returns false Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to add a block dynamically after the content, the block should load in every category and every product page and base on the category title or page title load some data from database and show.

I use controller_action_layout_load_before, and inside the method in observer class,

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('content');
```

returns false instead of an object.
I have to implement it for a client as a Magento module, I have no access to their template, I am using Magento 1.9 rwd/default

Answer (score 0):

I think that using `controller_action_layout_load_before` is not good; it is too early because the XML layout is not built yet.

Try to use event `controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before`.

Or maybe adding your own XML layout could be better solution. See http://alanstorm.com/adding-additional-layout-xml-updates-via-modules/